# How would i write a for loop for this code i have written

Tags: java, for-loop, char, boolean

I have written a java code that needs to have a for loop. I am unsure as how to write one for this program because i have only written for loops for int or doubles. I do not want a complete answer because i would really like to finish this code by myself. I just need a little help understanding how to write a for loop for this code.

The project was to write ao code that prompts a user to enter a sentence and it should display each character on the screen except space character(''). This is the code i have written. like i said above i am stuck as how to write a for loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LetterCase
{
 public static boolean isThisSpace(char sentence)
{
    if (sentence == ' ');
        { System.out.print(sentence + ":" + "space");
            return true;
            }
        }
public static boolean isThisUpperCase(char inputSentence)
{
    if(inputSentence >='A' && inputSentence <= 'Z')
        {
        System.out.print(inputSentence + ":" + "Upper case");
            return true;
            }
        return false;
        }
public static boolean isThisLowerCase(char inputSentence)
{
    if(inputSentence >= 'a' && inputSentence <= 'z')
        {
        System.out.print(inputSentence + ":" + "Lower Case");
            return true;
            }
        return false;
        }

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner keyboard_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a sentence : ");
    String sentence = keyboard_input.next();

    for(

    }
}
```

I also have a quick question as how to make my string sentence be able to be read as characters in the program. Thank you!

Comment: Quite frankly, please spend sometime on good basic Java tutorials and/or books before you can move on actual programming. This is reflected by your previous posts. One of them has been deleted for the purpose of moderation, the rest has/have been closed and this is also likely to be treated the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) method only reads a word. You should use [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method so that you can read the whole sentence.

[`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) method gives you a `char[]`. With that you can write a for loop just like you would do with `int`s and `double`s.

```
for(int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++) {
    //...
}
```

If you are interested, you can learn more about the `for` loop here - [The for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Dint the questioner say " I do not want a complete answer because i would really like to finish this code by myself. I just need a little help understanding how to write a for loop for this code." so giving details about the `Scanner` mistake is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the character array from the input sentence using the `toCharArray()` method of the `String` class.

You for loop would look like -

```
for(char c : sentence.toCharArray()) {
   <call the method>
}
```